# Identify when the UITableView loads the visible set of rows in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios

I am looking for the event that gets fired when the tableview loads the rows to fit the screen. I know tableview loads only the number of rows that fit the screen. I want to execute a set of code when the rows that fit the screen are loaded.

Any pointers on how to determine this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd need to implement [UITableViewDelegate](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/UIKit.UITableViewDelegate/) and override the WillDisplay(UITableView, UITableViewCell, NSIndexPath) method.  Be sure to set the delegate of your tableview to the class that implements UITableViewDelegate.

Unfortunately WillDisplay is called per cell, not per row.

Comment: I want to execute some code only after all the cells that fit the screen are loaded on screen. Since WillDisplay is called for every cell, how would I determine that visible screen is loaded with the cells that it can accomodate?

Answer (score 0):

I am not good at `c#`, so please translate this from `Swift`. I've added another solution down below which is, sort of a manual calculation of visible rows in `tableview`.

### The Recommended Solution:

```
var isFirstTime:Bool = true
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let indexPaths = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows {
        if indexPath == indexPaths.last {
            if isFirstTime {
                self.visibleCellsLoaded()
            }
            isFirstTime = false
        }
    }
}
```

The `isFirstTime` (Very important) flag will restrict your specific **"set of code"** (`self.visibleCellsLoaded()`) to execute only once. You can remove it if you want it to be executed every time you scroll - which apparently negates the purpose of your question.

---

#### Another solution that also works:

Here we manually calculate and get what `tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows` returns us *(Result is mostly similar to the previous method)*

```
fileprivate func getLastVisibleIndexPath() -> IndexPath {
    //This samples the first indexPath only, so this works only with rows that have static height, not with UITableViewAutomaticDimension.
    let firstIndexPath = IndexPath.init(row: 0, section: 0)
    let tableViewHeight = self.tableView.bounds.height
    let rowHeight = tableView.rectForRow(at: firstIndexPath).size.height
    
    let numberOfVisibleRows = tableViewHeight / rowHeight
    return IndexPath.init(row: Int(numberOfVisibleRows - 1), section: 0)
}

var isFirstTime:Bool = true
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {        
    if indexPath == getLastVisibleIndexPath() {
        if isFirstTime {
            self.visibleCellsLoaded()
        }
        isFirstTime = false
    }        
}
```

Comment: @Bhadhan : You solution will work. I will give it a try in c#. BTW the action which I want to take once all the visible cells are loaded is that "Moving one of the rows to left and revert back to show that row can be deleted by swiping".  It is a business requirement as we had a different UI for editing tableview.  DO you think a simple UIView animation to move cell to left would work here if I grab the cell to move left that has edit row enabled.

Comment: Do you want to automatically open the cell for editing?

Comment: Did the answer solve this specific question Other than opening cells for editing?

Comment: I have cells with dynamic height. So, did not use this solution.